# If $R[x]=R \oplus \langle x \rangle \oplus \langle x^2 \rangle \oplus \cdots $ is a grading of $R[x]$, and $r \in R$, then where does $rx$ belong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, graded-rings

> A graded ring is a ring $R$ with a decomposition $R=\bigoplus_{i \ge 0} R_i$ of the abelian group $(R, +)$ into a direct sum of abelian groups $R_i$ such that $R_i \cdot R_j \subset R_{i+j}$.

Consider $R[x]=R \oplus \langle x \rangle \oplus \langle x^2 \rangle \oplus \cdots$. Since each $R_i$ is just an abelian group, we can only add elements. So, for instance, $r \notin \langle x \rangle$.

So, where is $rx$ for some $r \in R$?

Comment: $R_0\cdot R_0\subset R_0$ means $R_0$ is a subring and $R_0 \cdot R_j \subset R_j$ means $R_j$ is a $R_0$ module

Comment: Well, where did you see the equation $R[x]=R \oplus \langle x \rangle \oplus \langle x^2 \rangle \oplus \cdots$?  What is the definition of $\langle x\rangle$?

Comment: @EricWofsey This is the definition and an example given in Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter $0$. Since each $R_i$ is an abelian group, I was thinking that $\langle x \rangle$ is the just the group generated by $x$. Is this not correct? What should $\langle x \rangle$ be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$rx\in Rx = \langle x\rangle$$
(In this notation, $\langle p(x)\rangle = R\cdot p(x)$)

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a $R$-module and not just a group?

Comment: @AlJebr . Yes, we're in the category of $R$-modules, so it is generated as an $R$-module.  There is a functor allowing us to view each $R_i$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (i.e. an abelian group) but that is still a different category.